# File is not running more than 5minutes even i set maximum_execution time in php file and php.ini file

Tags: php

I really don't know what exactly happens. I am running a file in which there is for loop and it reads the xml file which contains more than 11,000 items and i am inserting and updating the file in the website. When i run the script it is not executing more than 5 minutes. I googled the solution and found below answers:-

```
1.)ini_set('max_execution_time', 56700);
2.) ini_set('max_execution_time', -1);
3.) ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
4.) in php.ini max_execution_time  = 600//10minutes
```

i also made a file phpinfo.php where i used the phpinfo function and it is displaying the `maximum execution time =600//10` minutes but still my server is not executing it more than 5 minutes. I added time in my code to check for it.

I also added `ini_set('memory_limit', '1G');` to check if there is no memory limit problem but still no resolve

Please help me. ALso note that safe mode is off

Comment: Do you restart the server after changes... ? most probabaly yes :) just reminder.

Comment: I didnot restarted the server. i had those same kind of problem before but i solved it using the same code without restarting the server, dont know why this is not working this time

Comment: change only reflect if do what @IshaS says.

Comment: I restarted the server but not working

Comment: just add  `set_time_limit(-1);` at the top of your script

Comment: Where this `-1` comes from? The [documentation](https://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) clearly states: *"If set to zero, no time limit is imposed."*

Comment: @axiac true. I meant `0`, mixed this up with the `memory_limit`

Comment: @DarkBee set_time_limit(5); script works if i edit the time lesser than 300 seconds but if i exceeded the time then it stops at 300 seconds

Comment: If the webserver is Apache then the [Timeout](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#timeout) directive limits the script's execution time.

Comment: @axiac yes my web server is apache then how shall i edit or remove the 300 seconds   timeout limitation

Comment: If i change in the /usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf from timeout 300 to 1800 will it work?

Answer (score 0):

You can work around this problem with [set_time_limit()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) . Set that for every iteration of a loop and you should be fine. You can set the time limit to a few seconds (enough to execute one iteration of your loop). I have used that for scripts that ran for more than an hour, and it worked just fine.

For example, like this:

```
while(1) {
    set_time_limit(5);
    // do something complicated for less than 5 seconds
    // break your loop eventually
}
```

The big benefit of this approach is that you don't need to constantly tweak your settings for larger files, and that you can keep the timeouts where no large timespans were intended.

Comment: @DarkBee Setting it inside the loop i don't need to know how many iterations (and thus how much time) the total will take. But i still keep some control (i.e. still limiting to catch infinite loops or similar)

Comment: @DarkBee It's written in the [documentation](https://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php): *"When called, `set_time_limit()` restarts the timeout counter from zero"*. It is the official way to let the script to take as much time it needs to finish its job.

Comment: can you count the query output. it may be longer

Comment: @axiac it's overhead.. I rather set the time limit `0` to once than `5000000` times to `5`

Comment: set_time_limit(5); script works if i edit the time lesser than 300 seconds but if i exceeded the time then it stops at 300 seconds

Comment: The limitation to 300 seconds could come from the webserver.

Comment: you already had the 300 second (= 5 minute) limit, so it was to be expected that exceeding it here would not help. Try it inside the loop, or if you prefer set it to zero before the loop.

Comment: i placed set_time_limit(600); at the top of the php file

Comment: I thought so. But that is not how it works. Either set it to 0 on the top (or anywhere before the loop) to get infinite time, or set it so something smaller inside the loop. Take a look at the documentation, i linked it in my answer.

Comment: i added set_time_limit(0) but still it stops at 300 seconds.

Comment: maybe you could try what i suggested in my answer?

Comment: My code is complex and it will take more than 5 seconds to complete, it takes 40 seconds or more to complete

Comment: So you just set the time limit to 120 seconds or such, and you're good to go.

Comment: I added code set_time_limit(100); inside of my loop but still got stuck in 300 seconds. If i change in the /usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf from timeout 300 to 1800 will it work?

Comment: If you have found `Timeout 300` in your `httpd.conf` then that's the reason. Change it.